# Picasso load images from expansion file

Tags: android, gridview, picasso, expansion

In my Android application I want to display images in a GridView using Picasso. All of the images are in my expansion (obb) file. I can get the drawables from  the expansion file via InputStream but I don't know how can I load them with Picasso. My code so far:

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

public com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile expansionFile;
public String[] photoID;
public Integer photoNumberOf;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.photogridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("FILTER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String photoString = settings.getString("DESC_MainPhoto", null);
    photoID = photoString.split(",");
    photoNumberOf = photoID.length;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photoID.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {

            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;


        try {
            expansionFile = com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getActivity(), 2, 0);
            InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(photoID[position] + ".jpg");
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(fileStream, null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }


        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(???????????????????????????????)
                .resize(width, 0)

                .into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso provides 3 methods of loading images.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);        
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
```

You can use the second method when you know a File location.

Comment: That's sounds good, but what is the File location format for a jpg in the obb file?

Answer (score 0):

Use File method of Picasso

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(new File(path))
                .resize(width, 0)
                .into(imageView);
```